# Filtering Rows based on column condition before subtracting a column value

Tags: dplyr, filter

Im having trouble trying to 1) Filter out rows based on two conditions 2) subtract values based on the rows

For example, I have this table:

| importer | exporter | year | cn | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUS | CHN | 2000 | penaeus shrimps nei | 100 |
| AUS | CHN | 2000 | penaeus shrimps nei | 50 |
| CHN | AUS | 2000 | penaeus shrimps nei | 100 |
| AUS | SGP | 2001 | penaeus shrimps nei | 100 |
| SGP | AUS | 2001 | penaeus shrimps nei | 50 |
| AUS | CHN | 2003 | giant tiger prawn | 200 |
| AUS | CHN | 2003 | giant tiger prawn | 100 |
| CHN | AUS | 2003 | giant tiger prawn | 100 |

Firstly I want to filter out firstly based on the year which should look like this.

| importer | exporter | year | cn | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUS | CHN | 2000 | penaeus shrimps nei | 150 |
| CHN | AUS | 2000 | penaeus shrimps nei | 100 |
| AUS | SGP | 2001 | penaeus shrimps nei | 100 |
| SGP | AUS | 2001 | penaeus shrimps nei | 50 |
| AUS | CHN | 2003 | giant tiger prawn | 300 |
| CHN | AUS | 2003 | giant tiger prawn | 100 |

Next I want to create a new column called "redundant" which is bascially filtering out rows based on year and cn to determine the difference in quantity.

In summary it should filter by year, followed by importer/exporter relationship and cn before summarizing the quantity and taking the difference. I hope this makes sense!

It should look like this eventually:

| importer | exporter | year | cn | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUS | CHN | 2000 | penaeus shrimps nei | 50 |
| AUS | SGP | 2001 | penaeus shrimps nei | 50 |
| AUS | CHN | 2003 | giant tiger prawn | 200 |

Answer (score 0):

Would this approach solve your issue:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# the data
dat <- tribble(
  ~importer,    ~exporter,  ~year,  ~cn,    ~quantity,
"AUS", "CHN", 2000, "penaeus shrimps nei", 100,
"AUS", "CHN", 2000, "penaeus shrimps nei", 50,
"CHN", "AUS", 2000, "penaeus shrimps nei", 100,
"AUS", "SGP", 2001, "penaeus shrimps nei", 100,
"SGP", "AUS", 2001, "penaeus shrimps nei", 50,
"AUS", "CHN", 2003, "giant tiger prawn", 200,
"AUS", "CHN", 2003, "giant tiger prawn", 100,
"CHN", "AUS", 2003, "giant tiger prawn", 100
)

# the approach
dat %>% 
  # first: group by everything except quantity and sum it up
  group_by(across(!quantity)) %>% 
  summarise(quantity = sum(quantity)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  # next: self join with importer and exporter reversed ... 
  left_join(., ., by = c("importer" = "exporter",
                         "exporter" = "importer",
                         "year",
                         "cn"
                         )) %>% 
  # ... to calculate net quantity
  mutate(quantity = quantity.x - quantity.y) %>% 
  # finally some cleaning: drop quantity.x/.y vars
  select(!c(quantity.x, quantity.y)) %>% 
  # filter the rows you're interested in:
  filter(importer == "AUS")

#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'importer', 'exporter', 'year'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   importer exporter  year cn                  quantity
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>
#> 1 AUS      CHN       2000 penaeus shrimps nei       50
#> 2 AUS      CHN       2003 giant tiger prawn        200
#> 3 AUS      SGP       2001 penaeus shrimps nei       50
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Tim,

Thank you for your answer, I do have another column that states the production method (e.g. A or B) I was wondering whether its possible to also insert a string that matches the production methods before doing the subtraction?